# Canvas element does not resize when using ReactJS and PaperJS together

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, reactjs, paperjs

I have found that canvas elements correctly resize on window resize when they are inside react components. They also resize correctly when used with PaperJS. However, they do not resize when used with PaperJS and ReactJS together.

Is this an incompatibility between PaperJS and ReactJS or am I instantiating PaperJS incorrectly? I'm calling **paper.setup(canvas)** in the **componentDidMount** function of the react component which contains the canvas element. Is that the correct place to do this?

I've included code snippets below.

*Note: For some reason the "Run code snippet" feature complains on the ReactJS snippets, so I've included JSFiddle links which work fine.*

**PaperJS Only [SUCCESS] - Canvas resizes on window resize**
https://jsfiddle.net/eadlam/srmracev/

```js
// Instantiate the paperScope with the canvas element
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
paper.setup(myCanvas);

// Draw a circle in the center
var width = paper.view.size.width;
var height = paper.view.size.height;
var circle = new paper.Shape.Circle({
  center: [width / 2, height / 2],
  fillColor: 'grey',
  radius: 10
});

// render
paper.view.draw();
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.9.22/paper-core.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" resize="true"></canvas>
```

**ReactJS Only [SUCCESS] - Canvas resizes on window resize** https://jsfiddle.net/eadlam/0de1mpoa/

```js
var Canvas = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <canvas id="myCanvas" resize="true"></canvas>;
  }
});

React.render(<Canvas/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**ReactJS + HMTL5 Canvas [FAIL] - Canvas does not resize on window resize** 
https://jsfiddle.net/eadlam/jLo3opgq/

```js
var Canvas = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function () {
        // Instantiate the paperScope with the canvas element
        var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        paper.setup(myCanvas);
        
        // Draw a circle in the center
        var width = paper.view.size.width;
        var height = paper.view.size.height;
        var circle = new paper.Shape.Circle({
            center: [width / 2, height / 2],
            fillColor: 'grey',
            radius: 10
        });
        
        // render
        paper.view.draw();
    },

    render: function () {
        return <canvas id="myCanvas" resize="true"></canvas>;
    }
});

React.render(<Canvas/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.9.22/paper-core.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to use the `data-paper-resize` prop, since React doesn't recognize the `resize` prop.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" data-paper-resize />
```

See [Canvas Configuration](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/#canvas-configuration) and [Supported Attributes](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#supported-attributes).

Comment: When using it, it changes the x, y coordinates of drawn paths. When I use onClick methods on Path objects, I get shift mouse actions (meaning click in one place causes it to go to another)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this, for example:

Create a paper canvas element:

```
import React from 'react'
import paper from 'paper'
import './paperCanvas.css'

class PaperCanvas extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        // modify state with functions if necessary, and inherit objects from props
        this.state = {
            height: window.innerHeight,
            width: window.innerWidth,
            circle: undefined
        }
        this.updateDimensions = this.updateDimensions.bind(this);
        this.resizeMethod = this.resizeMethod.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        paper.setup('paperCanvas')
        this.state.circle = new paper.Path.Circle({
            center: paper.view.center,
            radius: 50,
            fillColor: 'orange'
        })
        paper.view.draw()
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeMethod)
    }

    updateDimensions() {
        this.setState({
           height: window.innerHeight,
           width: window.innerWidth
         });
    }

    resizeMethod(){
        this.updateDimensions()
        this.state.circle.position = new paper.Point(this.state.width/2, this.state.height/2)
        console.log(this.state.width/2, this.state.height/2)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <canvas id="paperCanvas" 
                height={this.state.height}
                width={this.state.width}>
            </canvas>
        )
    }
}

export default PaperCanvas
```

In paperCanvas.css:

```
#paperCanvas {
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}
```